# Django + uwsgi + ngnix + debug off = Server Error (500)

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to set up a production server that consists of Django + uwsgi + Nginx.
The tutorial I'm following is located here http://www.panta.info/blog/3/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-uwsgi-and-django-on-ubuntu.html

The production server is working because I can see the admin page when debug is on but when I turn to debug off. It displays the  Server Error (500) again. I don't know what to do. Ngnix should be serving the Django request. I'm clueless right now, Can someone kindly help me, please.

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com_error.log;


  location / {
    uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/mysite.com.sock;
    include     uwsgi_params;
  }



  location /media/  {
    alias /home/projects/mysite/media/;
  }



  location  /static/ {
   alias  /home/projects/mysite/static/;
  }
}
```

my /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/mysite.com.ini

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/mysite.com.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
wsgi-file = /home/projects/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/projects/venv
chdir = /home/projects/mysite
touch-reload = /home/projects/mysite/reload
```

my settings.py

```
root@localhost:~# cat /home/projects/mysite/mysite/settings.py
# Django settings for my site project.

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG





min/css/base.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 160.19.332.22, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "160.19.332.22"
2013/06/17 14:33:39 [error] 8346#0: *13 open() "/home/projects/mysite/static/admin/css/login.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 160.19.332.22, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1", host: "174.200.14.200"
2013/06/17 14:33:39 [error] 8346#0: *14 open() "/home/projects/mysite/static/admin/css/base.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 160.19.332.22, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "174.200.14.2007", referrer: "http://174.200.14.200/admin/"
2013/06/17 14:33:39 [error] 8346#0: *15 open() "/home/projects/mysite/static/admin/css/login.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 160.19.332.22, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1", host: "174.200.14.200", referrer: "http://174.200.14.200/admin/"
```

Comment: You need to find out what the actual python error message is in your logs that is causing the 500

Comment: I posted it timmy , its weird . Everything works fine when debug is on and when it is off , everything go bizzare

Comment: Are you using `django-compressor` or something similar to create minified static files?

Comment: Make sure you have you set [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in your settings.

Comment: @Alasdair I don't have a domain set up but i'm setting my production server on vps and when I used the vps ip for the allowed host it doesn't work

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony nope , i'm not using django-compressor . I think its ALLOWED_HOST . I'm running vps on production and I don't have a domain yet so I input the vps ip into the allowed_host field. and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it's your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting (new in Django 1.5)

Try the following in your `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This will allow everything to connect until you get your domain name sorted.

It's worth saying that when you do get a domain name sorted make sure you update this value (list of allowed domain names). As the documentation for [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) states:

> This is a security measure to prevent an attacker from poisoning
>   caches and password reset emails with links to malicious hosts by
>   submitting requests with a fake HTTP Host header, which is possible
>   even under many seemingly-safe webserver configurations.

Also (a little aside) - I don't know if you have a different setup for your django settings per environment but this is what I do:

At the end of your `settings.py` include:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then in the same directory as `settings.py` create a `local_settings.py` file (and a `__init__.py` file if using a different structure than the initial template) and set your settings per environment there. Also exclude `local_settings.py` from your version control system.

e.g. I have `DEBUG=False` in my `settings.py` (for a secure default) but can override with `DEBUG=True` in my development local settings.

I also keep all my database info in my local settings file so it's not in version control.

Just a little info if you didn't know it already :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in my case it turned out to be that `STATICFILES_STORAGE` was incorrectly set as:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

This question has already an accepted answer but I'm leaving this in case someone gets here in the same situation. You can also see this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191966/5028468) for the same error.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have never guessed that this was the problem