# Debugging django on nginx Server Error (500)

Tags: django, debugging, nginx

Running django on nginx on my staging server I've got Server Error (500). Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150426/django-uwsgi-ngnix-debug-off-server-error-500) I've set

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

But that did not solve my problem.

Does anyone know how I can see djangos exceptions?

Comment: Try to use https://getsentry.com/welcome/

Answer (score 2):

Django sends an E-Mail to all **ADMINS**, when **DEBUG** is False and some **EMAIL_*** settings are properly set.

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/error-reporting/

You can also setup an appropriate logging to do that:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/

for more information.